# jQuery accessing JSON elements

Tags: jquery, json

I have this JSON string:

```
{"image":[
    {"img":"_files\/image\/images\/firstimage.jpg","alt":"firstimage alt text"},
    {"img":"secondimage.jpg","alt":"secondimage alt text"}
]}
```

The JSON string is picked from a textarea, then stored in the variable 'content'

```
var content = $("textarea").val();
```

**I am trying to access the elements:**

```
alert(content["image"][0]["img"]);
```

**But I get error:**

> TypeError: content.image is undefined.

Eventually I want to manipulate the JSON string by changing and adding elements.

What am I doing wrong here?

**UPDATE**

$.parseJSON did the job:

```
var content = $.parseJSON($("textarea").val());
```

Comment: try this `var content = Eval($("textarea").val());` you must convert it a `json` object

Comment: I had to make Eval less eval by removing the capital E ;-) Now I get a little bit further and am running into the error

    SyntaxError: invalid label

Comment: What do you get when you do a console.log(content);?

Comment: @DON: *Never* use `eval` for parsing JSON!!!

Comment: learned en forgot again, despite that, @DON : thanks for taking the effort!

Comment: Just for reference: you were getting that error in `eval` because JavaScript interprets the outer `{ }` as a block rather than an object literal. You need to wrap the string with parentheses `( )` before passing it to `eval` to make sure it gets treated as an object. Nevertheless, `eval` is evil and `$.parseJSON` (or `JSON.parse` in native JavaScript) is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're picking the JSON *string* from a textarea, you must first convert it to a JavaScript object, before using it. Use, e.g., [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/):

```
var content = $.parseJSON( $("textarea").val() );
```

Alternatively, there is a native JavaScript function [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) in [most browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=json) to do this:

```
var content = JSON.parse( $("textarea").val() );
```

Answer (score 3):

It won't parse straight to JSON instead you'll need to first do

```
var content = JSON.parse($("textarea").val());
```

This should then allow you to use general JSON manipulation

Example of your JSON retrieval could be something like this

```
content.image[0]['alt']
```